# Hide the url that appears in the upper right corner when printing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, printing

The problem is that when I print using javascript the url always appears in the corner. I need hide or delete that url. Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you try using @media print{} to hide ?

Comment: I try that but it dosent work